# Escape and remove characters (dynamic content) in a logic app

Tags: azure, escaping, azure-logic-apps, azure-log-analytics, azure-sentinel

I've been trying to fetch data from a REST API and then add it into Log Analytics in Azure using a Logic app. My issue is that it seems that I need to escape some characters in the body of the request to Log Analytics since I get a 400 with the error message:

> {
> "Error": "InvalidDataFormat",
> "Message": null
> }

I've checked and the JSON body is not valid.

My JSON request body looks like this:

```
{
"assetid": "TBD Assetid",
"vulnid": "@{items('For_each')?['id']}",
"key": "@{items('For_each_3')?['key']}",
"proof": "@{items('For_each_3')?['proof']}",
"since": "@{items('For_each_3')?['since']}",
"status": "@{items('For_each_3')?['status']}
}
```

The actual request looks like this:

```
{
"assetid": "TBD",
"vulnid": "adobe-flash-apsb15-11-cve-2015-3096",
"key": "C:\WINDOWS\system32\Macromed\Flash\",
"proof": "<p><p>Vulnerable OS: Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter Edition<p></p></p><p>Vulnerable software installed: Adobe Flash 17.0.0.188 (C:\WINDOWS\system32\Macromed\Flash\)</p></p>",
"since": "2021-05-10T11:41:03.483Z",
"status": "vulnerable-version"
}
```

The issue seems to be the backslashes and the paragraphs elements.

I would like to escape the backslashes in "key" and "proof" and remove the paragraphs element. I've tried to search for a solution but most of the examples are with static strings and the replace function.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the replace functions to remove the escape characters & paragraph elements for the key parameter

For Key parameter:

```
replace(variables('string2'),'\',''
```

You can also use replace for the proof parameter as well below is the expression.

For proof parameter :

```
replace(replace(replace(variables('string1'),'<p>',''),'</p>',''),'\',''))
```

Here is the sample output for reference using the replace functions

[image]

Based on the above requirement , we understood that every time a html tag that is getting added to proof parameter might be different if that is the case " replace function () " wont help you.

To remove those  html characters  you can adopt any of the below 2 methods:

1. using the [Html to text content version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/conversionservice/) connector
2. Using [Azure functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/tutorial-process-email-attachments-workflow) as described in this article.

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for the explanation! I used replace(items('For_each')?['key'], '\', '\\') while in a loop, that works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the accepted answer is the [Compose action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations?tabs=consumption#compose-action), which allows you to construct a *valid* JSON payload from multiple inputs. This includes escaping invalid JSON input.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).